# How can I check the logging message and the method called my unittests?

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, python-mock

I'm using Django 1.3 and need to check the output and number of interactions in my logging system. For logging I'm using Django-Sentry though it appears that it's working just like the regular Python logger.

I'm using python-mockito for mocking and if possible I would like to check the number of times different methods have been called and the messages they return.

I'm trying to achieve a check that does something like:

```
from foo import views
logger = mock()
views.logger = logger
do_method()
verify(logger).error(any, any)
do_method()
verifyZeroInteractions(logger)
```

Also being able to check the parameters would be nice.

`models.py`:

```
from django.db import models
import logging
from sentry.client.handlers import SentryHandler

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

try:
    is_logging_setup = True
except NameError:
    is_logging_setup = True
    logger.setLevel(settings.LOGGING_LEVEL)
    logger.addHandler(SentryHandler())

class Foo(models.Model):
    def bar(self):
        logger.warning("Rawr", 'extra': { 'data': 'foo' })
```

`tests.py`:

```
class TestModelFoo(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.foo = Foo()

    def test_getting_logged(self):
        self.foo.bar()
        # Check the log output.
```

Any suggestions on how I can catch the output?

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code that does just that with the standard `mock` python library.

```
    with mock.patch('infra.manifest.fake_put') as fake_patch:
        infra.manifest.copy_files(root, files, folder, True)

    args, kwargs = fake_patch.call_args

    self.assertEqual((u'/etc/a.tmp', u'/tmp/a.tmp'), args)
    self.assertEqual({'use_sudo': True}, kwargs)
```

It's the `mock.patch` method you're interested in. I think there are other frameworks where you can specify a `passthrough` keyword which will also call the original method, this one will turn the patched method into a mock call and not call the original method.